# Отправить Map() через Ajax

Tags: javascript, php

Как отправить коллекцию Map через Ajax ?

```
var arrMap = new Map([['test','value_1],['test2','value_2']])

$.ajax ... data: { datas: arrMap } ...
```

По итогу ничего не отправляется.

Proof

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что, наверное, в консоль на наличие ошибок надо смотреть?

Comment: `in` - зарезервированное слово

Comment: @teran, оч смешно. Наверное их нет ? Даже проверял содержимое коллекции. Все четко. В Ajax не отправляется.

Comment: @Deonis, это в качестве примера..с любым названием такое. Исправил

Comment: вам обязательно использовать `Map` ? либо конвертите в объект/массив, либо изначально используйте объект. мап не сериализуется в json напрямую

Comment: на стороне php посмотрите `file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: Пробуйте так: `data: Object.fromEntries(_in)` где `_in` переменная с присвоенным объектом `Map`

Comment: @ArchDemon нечего там смотреть, map не сериализуется на стороне js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формально говоря, в исходном виде - никак. `Map` не сериализуется (*map ведь это не просто пары ключ значение, но и сохранение порядка ключей и типы ключа могут быть произвольны, а не только строка/число*). У вас есть несколько вариантов решения проблемы:

- Перед отправкой конвертировать `map`  в обычный объект. Самый простой способ будет `Object.fromEntries`, но он пока что охватывает [порядка 90% глобальных пользователей](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_fromentries), поэтому возможно придется другими способами перебрать ключи словаря и сформировать объект.
- Возможно, не стоит использовать `Map` изначально. Чаще всего для этих целей используют обычный объект, и тогда вопроса сериализации не будет. Ваш исходный массив легко преобразуется в объект с помощью `arr.reduce((acc,v) => (acc[v[0]] = v[1], acc), {})`
- преобразовать `map` в массив массивов пар ключ-значение, подобный тому, как у вас в коде задано начальное значение при создании map. Реализация тоже не замысловатая, но на стороне пхп придется пересобирать обратно, что вряд ли целесообразно.